# Create an automated, daily send of previous day email click activity heatmaps

Tags: marketing-cloud

I've not seen anywhere in SFMC where it's possible to do this, but I'm hoping that there's some method I've just not discovered yet. What we would like to do is to either add a step to automations which after a set number of days will generate and deliver to specific users the click activity overlay report (as pdf) of the email in the automation OR, to create a daily task that will return the heat maps from all emails sent a set number of days prior (generally 6). However, I'm unable to find anywhere in the documentation where this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The data exists in the platform, but there's no good out-of-the-box way to do what you're asking.

You can use Query Activities to aggregate the click data from the [**_Job**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_job/) and [**_Click**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_click/) data views and write it to a Data Extension.

Then, with some AMPScript in an email, you can generate a table that lists link aliases (`linkname`) ordered by number of clicks.